# Why do I get a type error in this program when I add an unrelated definition?

Tags: haskell

I was showing a coworker `Free` when I ran into a curious GHC behavior I don’t really understand. Here is a simple, contrived program that typechecks:

```
import Prelude hiding (readFile, writeFile)
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Functor.Sum

data FileSystemF a
  = ReadFile FilePath (String -> a)
  | WriteFile FilePath String a
  deriving (Functor)

data ConsoleF a
  = WriteLine String a
  deriving (Functor)

data CloudF a
  = GetStackInfo String (String -> a)
  deriving (Functor)

type App = Free (Sum FileSystemF (Sum ConsoleF CloudF))

readFile :: FilePath -> App String
readFile path = liftF (InL (ReadFile path id))

writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> App ()
writeFile path contents = liftF (InL (WriteFile path contents ()))
```

I tried adding another definition, but it wasn’t quite right:

```
writeLine :: String -> App ()
writeLine line = liftF (InR (WriteLine line ()))
```

The problem here is that I was missing another `InL`. The correct definition should be this:

```
writeLine :: String -> App ()
writeLine line = liftF (InR (InL (WriteLine line ())))
```

However, that isn’t the point. What’s weird to me is the type error that GHC produced when I added my first, incorrect definition of `writeLine`. Specifically, it produced *two* type errors:

```
/private/tmp/free-sandbox/src/FreeSandbox.hs:26:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘ConsoleF’ with ‘Sum ConsoleF CloudF’
        arising from a functional dependency between constraints:
          ‘MonadFree
             (Sum FileSystemF (Sum ConsoleF CloudF))
             (Free (Sum FileSystemF (Sum ConsoleF CloudF)))’
            arising from a use of ‘liftF’ at src/FreeSandbox.hs:26:27-66
          ‘MonadFree
             (Sum FileSystemF ConsoleF)
             (Free (Sum FileSystemF (Sum ConsoleF CloudF)))’
            arising from a use of ‘liftF’ at src/FreeSandbox.hs:29:18-48
    • In the expression: liftF (InL (WriteFile path contents ()))
      In an equation for ‘writeFile’:
          writeFile path contents = liftF (InL (WriteFile path contents ()))
   |
26 | writeFile path contents = liftF (InL (WriteFile path contents ()))
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/private/tmp/free-sandbox/src/FreeSandbox.hs:29:18: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Sum ConsoleF CloudF’ with ‘ConsoleF’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadFree
                        (Sum FileSystemF ConsoleF)
                        (Free (Sum FileSystemF (Sum ConsoleF CloudF)))’
            arising from a use of ‘liftF’
          instance ‘MonadFree f (Free f)’ at <no location info>
    • In the expression: liftF (InR (WriteLine line ()))
      In an equation for ‘writeLine’:
          writeLine line = liftF (InR (WriteLine line ()))
   |
29 | writeLine line = liftF (InR (WriteLine line ()))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The second of the two errors (the one on line 29) makes sense. It’s an error I would expect. But the error on line 26 completely baffles me. The definition of `writeFile` is correct! Adding my incorrect definition of `writeLine` shouldn’t have any effect on `writeFile`, right? What’s going on?

I was able to reproduce this on GHC 8.0.2 and GHC 8.2.1. I’d like to know if this is a bug in GHC (so I can report it) or if it’s an issue with my code that I don’t understand.

Comment: Oh this is a great one. Notice that if you put the incorrect `writeLine` definition _before_ the other definitions the questionable error vanishes. :)

Comment: I have opened [GHC Trac #14327](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14327) to track this issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be FD related, since specializing `liftF' :: Functor f => f a -> Free f a` gets rid of the extra error. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a GHC bug. It was fixed in commit [48daaaf0bba279b6e362ee5c632de69ed31ab65d (Don't report fundep wanted/wanted errors)](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/changeset/48daaaf0bba279b6e362ee5c632de69ed31ab65d/ghc), according to Ryan Scott.